# IIS redirect certain IPs to url

Tags: iis, redirect

I need to be able to redirect all German users who arrive at http://mysite.com to http://mysite.com/de-de/. Does IIS have this sort of IP routing built in, or is it best to use an ASP.net code solution?

As I understand it: to accurately redirect all German IPs you need to create and redirect an IP table for Germany. This is about 1000 IP ranges. ipaddresslocation.org/ip_ranges/get_ranges.php

Answer (score 3):

IIS has a rewrite/redirect module; whether it will do the GeoIP stuff you think you need is a whole other issue.  But really, just because someone's using what some GeoIP database thinks might be a german IP address, does that really mean that the user wants their content in German?  Of course not.  They could be a tourist, or someone who prefers to use English, or the GeoIP database might be dead wrong (gasp!  say it ain't so!)  You should respect the user's choice of language (made via the `Accept-Language` header) and not make choices for the user based on erroneous data.

Comment: I have to say I agree and have made this point, but you try persueding my client... ;-)

Comment: OK, give me their contact details.

Comment: Not going to happen, but thanks lol